# Dynamic named range not working when referred with indirect

Tags: excel, vba

I have some Dynamic named Ranges in my sheet.Ive made them dynamic using the following formula:

=$A$1:rowend($A$1)

Where row end is a custom function which return the last cell before an empty cell is reached in row "A"

The named range is named as follows : "iec_air"
There is also another named range : "iec_ground"

Now the problem is when i apply datavalidation on a cell and choose list referring to "iec_air" directly it works but when try to achieve the same thing using indirect("iec_"&"air") it doesnt work

When my named ranges were static it was working,not its not.Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can you create a new name which refers to `=indirect("iec_"&"air")` and use the new name as your validation list?

Comment: To work with dynamic ranges see this :) http://www.contextures.com/xldataval02.html

Comment: @SiddharthRout i am using the same technique..the thing is if my validation lists are a formula instead of static reference then indirect wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how to use VBA? 
One of the things you can do is create an event in a sheet module and adapt the size of the named range dynamically based on the blank cell.

Example

```
Sub setRangeDynamically()

dim oRange     as range

'Set range from cell(1,1) until the first blank cell downwards
set oRange = thisworkbook.sheets("blabla").range(cells(1,1),cells(1,1).end(xldown))
thisworkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersTo:=oRange 
end sub
```

To create the data validation:

```
With thisworkbook.sheets("BlaBla").range("B2").Validation 
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _ 
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=MyRange" 
End With
```

Comment: This would be the correct approach.  Dynamic Named ranges and INDIRECT() formulas do not play nice, so the named ranges will need to be static.  Through VBA like this, you retain "dynamic" in a different way.

Comment: i know this approach but having about 100 named ranges i was being quite hesitant for writing code for each and every one.

Comment: Set a range, using <<hierarchy>>.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row (and column), to make sure you don't miss out anything, set the size of an array and manipulate the data dynamically based on key words? I have no idea what users will be copy pasting or what you actually mean...